# New classes not included in project after re-opening the solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've been banging my head up against the wall with this one for a little while and I'd be very grateful if someone could help me out.

Here's what happens:

1. I make a new class in a .cs file
2. I close the solution
3. I open the solution, and the new file is no longer included

Nothing I do through the VS2013 UI will make that file permanently include. I have to manually open the project in a text editor and add a line like this:

```
<Compile Include="Test\TestClass.cs" />
```

Manually.

We are using TFS, but I seem to be the only person this is happening too, and it doesn't happen all the time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have security issues accessing the project file? Check the security on the `csproj` file (owner, write rights, etc).

Comment: When saving the project do you encounter any errors?

Comment: your csproj file is not getting modified

Comment: Check-out the project, add the file, and check-in again

Comment: After adding a file, use CTRL-SHIFT-S to save all files in the solution, the project files and the solution file itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried all of the above things to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

If you have multiple versions of VS2013 open at once, for some reason the project xmls don't save correctly.

Posting this here because I couldn't find anything about this elsewhere, so hopefully this will help other people.